# position the diaglog box right side of the window

Tags: jquery

I like to create a dialog box when clicked on a link as the following example. It works so far but the dialog box is always appear on the center window. I like to change this and position it to be on the right side of the window. Any ideas how I can tackle this?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

          $(function() {
          $("#lin").click(function(){
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
           });
      });
});
```

html:

```
<li><a id="lin" href="#">link</a></li>

    <div id="dialog" class="def" title="title" style="display:none;">
       <p>thi is the text in the dialog</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [jquery ui docs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Dialog#option-position) specify a position attribute that you can add that will position it either:

1. a single string representing position within viewport: 'center', 'left', 'right', 'top', 'bottom'.
2. an array containing an x,y coordinate pair in pixel offset from left, top corner of viewport (e.g. [350,100])
3. an array containing x,y position string values (e.g. ['right','top'] for top right corner).

   `$( "#dialog" ).dialog({position:'right'});`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `position:` option:

```
position: { my: "right", at: "right", of: window }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes read the jquery UI doc can be helpful:

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({position:'right'});
```